# How do I wrap text in table (LaTeX)?

Tags: tables

I have been trying to include this table in my LaTeX document, but can't get it to work.

**Code**

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Anode Voltage (kV)} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Peak Intensity of Cu K (Counts)} & \multirow{2}{*}{Average Peak Intensity (Counts)} & \multirow{2}{*}{Standard Deviation} \\ \cline{2-4}
 & Reading 1 & Reading 2 & Reading 3 &  &  \\ \hline
12 & 1195603 & 1217383 & 1243457 & 1218814 & ± 23959 \\ \hline
14 & 2843477 & 2902688 & 2956431 & 2900865 & ± 56499 \\ \hline
16 & 5323053 & 5638567 & 5476203 & 5479274 & ± 157779 \\ \hline
18 & 7825059 & 8089811 & 7906875 & 7940581 & ± 135556 \\ \hline
20 & 14743612 & 14799927 & 15101689 & 14881742 & ± 192549 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

**Output**

[image: Tabular Output]

I even tried using Tabulary, but then I run into another issue.

**Code**

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{|C|C|C|C|C|C|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Anode Voltage (kV)} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Peak Intensity of Cu K (Counts)} & \multirow{2}{*}{Average Peak Intensity (Counts)} & \multirow{2}{*}{Standard Deviation} \\ \cline{2-4}
 & Reading 1 & Reading 2 & Reading 3 &  &  \\ \hline
12 & 1195603 & 1217383 & 1243457 & 1218814 & ± 23959 \\ \hline
14 & 2843477 & 2902688 & 2956431 & 2900865 & ± 56499 \\ \hline
16 & 5323053 & 5638567 & 5476203 & 5479274 & ± 157779 \\ \hline
18 & 7825059 & 8089811 & 7906875 & 7940581 & ± 135556 \\ \hline
20 & 14743612 & 14799927 & 15101689 & 14881742 & ± 192549 \\ \hline
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}
```

**Output**

[image: Tabulary Output]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

One possible solution that seems to work is given below. However, this reduces the total width of the table too much.

**Code**

```
\begin{table}[]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Anode Voltage (kV)} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Peak Intensity of Cu K (Counts)} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{Average Peak Intensity (Counts)} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{Standard Deviation} \\ \cline{2-4}
   & Reading 1 & Reading 2 & Reading 3 &          &          \\ \hline
12 & 1195603   & 1217383   & 1243457   & 1218814  & ± 23959  \\ \hline
14 & 2843477   & 2902688   & 2956431   & 2900865  & ± 56499  \\ \hline
16 & 5323053   & 5638567   & 5476203   & 5479274  & ± 157779 \\ \hline
18 & 7825059   & 8089811   & 7906875   & 7940581  & ± 135556 \\ \hline
20 & 14743612  & 14799927  & 15101689  & 14881742 & ± 192549 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE ... Try with `tabularx` or define the column in para mode, i.e., `p{3pc}` instead of `c"

Comment: @MadyYuvi Thanks for your reply. Even after using tabularx, I get the same result and tabulary. I wanted to refrain from the explicit declaration of table width, so is there any way to automatically arrange the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this way--

[image]

```
\begin{table}[]\setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.5in}p{1in}p{1in}p{1in}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1in}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1in}}
        \hline
        {Anode Voltage (kV)} & 
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Peak Intensity of Cu K (Counts)} & 
        {Average Peak Intensity (Counts)} & 
        {Standard Deviation} \\ 
        \cline{2-4}
        & Reading 1 & Reading 2 & Reading 3 &  &  \\ \hline
        12 & 1195603 & 1217383 & 1243457 & 1218814 & ± 23959 \\ \hline
        14 & 2843477 & 2902688 & 2956431 & 2900865 & ± 56499 \\ \hline
        16 & 5323053 & 5638567 & 5476203 & 5479274 & ± 157779 \\ \hline
        18 & 7825059 & 8089811 & 7906875 & 7940581 & ± 135556 \\ \hline
        20 & 14743612 & 14799927 & 15101689 & 14881742 & ± 192549 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```